# What is the proper way to handle browser reload in Angular 10 ASP.NET Core 3.1 SPA application?

Tags: angular, single-page-application, asp.net-core-3.1

I have been working with the [Content Reactor sample app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/serverless-eventing-platform-for-microservices/serverless-eventing-platform-for-microservices/) from Microsoft.  I have upgraded the versions of Angular, .NET Standard, .NET Core and various NuGet packages.  The app now uses Angular 10 and ASP.NET Core 3.1 with endpoint routing.

I understand that `SpaServices/UseSpa()` is being deprecated.

```
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501
        });
```

The site is working on localhost in development/Visual Studio.  However, a browser reload is resulting in a 404 error (e.g., for https://localhost:2297/home). I understand this is probably due to the SPA nature of the app.

Given the deprecation of SpaServices, what is the correct way to support browser button reload?

Update: The app is being deployed to Microsoft Azure App Service.  The app uses SignalR.

Comment: (How) did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a web.config file for your IIS Server that redirects the 404 to the index.html so that Angular can handle them, e.g.:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
    <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```